# Error in processing request Error code: 200. Error text: OK (rejected). It seems that the connection to server has been lost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added the following code to add a new server to phpMyAdmin:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'cat';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '129.111.21.444';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

now, when I go to phpMyAdmin page, I see a drop down that I can use to connect to my desired server. After clicking the server name, I see a page where I should enter my user name and password. Once I do it, I can see the db on the left hand but I also see the following error:

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

When I try to click on the db, it gets me back to the log in page.

A screenshot of the error is also attached:[image]
I have updated phpMyAdmin as well, but, it did not help. Any other solution please?

Comment: Seems like your server cut out. Can you confirm the MySQL server process is still running? The server usually keeps a log of any errors or problems it encounters.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I faced that problem and finally found the solution:
Go to *Chrome settings -> Privacy & security -> Site settings -> Cookies & site data* -> Allow it if blocked.
Enjoy it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `https://` in front of the URL at the address bar works for me due to Chrome's security policy

Comment: her bro. Thank for the solution. It is works form me. I have faced many different error on different page like export and tried to change the password for it but nothing is working for me. But when I have used your solution and it's really work for me. Thank you again.

Comment: My issue was indeed due to the url. I had added a `/`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this line in config phpMyAdmin:
sudo gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 21600;
```

and change this parameter in php.ini:
sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or your path of this file.

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 21600
```

and restart apache:
sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Hi I tried your solution but I still have the same problem